# NoMethodError undefined method `participant'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mailboxer

I have mailboxer gem setup and when I visit /conversations I receive a `undefined method`participant' ` The error points to the Conversations controller with the index. I added a conversations instance variable to the index action that will contain all of the user’s inbox messages.

Can someone spot where I went wrong in my definition?

Conversations controller:

```
 helper_method :mailbox, :conversation

  def index
      @conversations ||= current_user.mailbox.inbox.all
    end

    def reply
      current_user.reply_to_conversation(conversation, *message_params(:body, :subject))
      redirect_to conversation
    end

    def trash_folder     
      @trash ||= current_user.mailbox.trash.all  
       end 


    def create
      recipient_emails = conversation_params(:recipients).split(',')
      recipients = User.where(email: recipient_emails).all

      conversation = current_user.
        send_message(recipients, *conversation_params(:body, :subject)).conversation

      redirect_to conversation
    end

    def reply
      current_user.reply_to_conversation(conversation, *message_params(:body, :subject))
      redirect_to conversation
    end

    def trash
      conversation.move_to_trash(current_user)
      redirect_to :conversations
    end

    def untrash
      conversation.untrash(current_user)
      redirect_to :conversations
    end

    private

    def mailbox
      @mailbox ||= current_user.mailbox
    end

    def conversation
      @conversation ||= mailbox.conversations.find(params[:id])
    end

    def conversation_params(*keys)
      fetch_params(:conversation, *keys)
    end

    def message_params(*keys)
      fetch_params(:message, *keys)
    end

    def fetch_params(key, *subkeys)
      params[key].instance_eval do
        case subkeys.size
        when 0 then self
        when 1 then self[subkeys.first]
        else subkeys.map{|k| self[k] }
        end
      end
    end
  end
```

Routes:

```
resources :users do |user|

 end

 resources :messages do
   member do
     post :new
   end
 end
 resources :conversations do
   member do
     post :reply
     post :trash
     post :untrash
   end
  collection do
     get :trashbin
     post :empty_trash
  end
end
```

Comment: What is the exact error message you're getting? A complete error message will include the receiver (e.g. `"foo"` in `undefined method \`bar' for "foo":String`) and the file and line number where the error occurred.

Comment: The error is from the index, `@conversations ||= current_user.mailbox.inbox.all` The exact error message is `undefined method participant for #<Class:0x00000108b1cf70>` NoMethodError

Comment: Hello, did you add `acts_as_messageable` to your User model? Also, did you manually create the conversations model? That may be the issue if you did. The mailboxer install script should take care of that configuration for you.

Comment: If you already have a conversations model (which it looks like you do) I would delete the model, rerun the install script, and rerun rake db:migrate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could finally reproduce your issue, I solved it by running:

```
rails g mailboxer:install
```

and

```
rake db:migrate
```

You will probably need to do something about your existing `conversations` table in your db.

Comment: I could finally reproduce the error you were getting, please see the answer.

Comment: I followed that step when I first started working on mailboxes. I just repeated the step and I receive the same error. The controller I posted does not work, however if I revert to the provided controller from the github example then that page works.

Comment: I'm out of clues. Can you reproduce the error in a minimal rails app and post the link to that repo?

Comment: Thanks for trying. I think the error could be due to the model. I may need to properly configure my conversations model.